# For matlab clustering, can centroid linkage work for distances other than Euclidean?

Tags: matlab, hierarchical-clustering, centroid

If I am doing hierarchical clustering, if I am using centroid linkage with a distance function other than Euclidean, say, for example, minkowski distance with an exponent of 3 as opposed to 2, will that necessarily not work? What would matlab do if it was given centroid linkage and a Minkowski distance with an exponent fo 3 so that it was not simply Euclidean distance?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`linkage`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/linkage.html) function define other distances. Examples are included in the link.

Comment: I did recognize it.  I was just wondering if there was any specific reason I wasn't aware of in matlab that using centroid linkage with a distance function other than Euclidean would cause problems or if matlab would evaluate the centroids of clusters and then link them together just as it would centroid linkage using ordinary Euclidean distance.  Does that help clarify the question?

Comment: My question is not one of how to use matlab to make hierarchical clusters using linkage and distance functions.  I know how to do that. It is if centroid linkage is used with a distance function such as, for example, Minkowski with an exponent of 1 or 3 as opposed to 2 if there would necessarily be problems or an inability for matlab to cluster the data correctly?

Comment: As I understand it, centroid is only for Euclidian Geometry (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81481/why-does-k-means-clustering-algorithm-use-only-euclidean-distance-metric)